# How to load image in GPUImageView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

```
@IBOutlet weak var gpuImageView: GPUImageView!
let image = GPUImagePicture(image: UIImage(named: "photo"))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.image.addTarget(self.gpuImageView)
    self.image.processImage()

}
```

My code crashs with signal `SIGABRT`.

1. I installed `GPUImage` (filter with `UIImage` works but slowly).
2. I create `UIView`(named it `GPUImageView`) and dragged it to `UIViewController`.

Comment: see if you have any unused outlets connected to your view

Comment: @Mr.T, I have only one outlet to this View.